# Could not load type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.JwtTokenProviderFactory

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

When trying to use a command defined in TEAMsFX I get a error message
System.TypeLoadException
HResult=0x80131522
Message=Could not load type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.JwtTokenProviderFactory' from assembly 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector, Version=4.21.1.0
from builder.Services.AddSingleton(sp =>

running a bot command

Comment: Could you please provide detailed steps on how the error occurs? Additionally, it would be helpful to know the specific versions of the dependencies in your project, such as `Microsoft.TeamsFx` and `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core`, along with the version of Visual Studio you’re using.

Comment: @YiqingZhao I followed steps in GettingStarted.md to enable SSO and later added package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt in effort to resolve this error.
teamsFX v. 2.4.0 Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core v. 4.18.1
Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.9.3

Comment: Could you please share which comment you have used ?

Comment: @vikram-MSFT do you mean command?

Comment: I' trying to build a TEAMs bot for chat command and added ITeamsCommandHandler

Comment: Could you please share the documentation to know the step by step procedure ?

Comment: After removing Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens package and updating the Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core to latest exception is solved